# Passing buffer for recv() and send() from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI wrapper for a C++ class which I create several instances of in a C# application, and this works fine, except for the functions in the C++ code which take a buffer from the calling function and fill it with whatever is received a call to recv, similarly some functions take a packet to be sent as a parameter.

In the C++ code there are several structs that define all the packet structures, pointers to which are taken as parameters, and I have equivalent C# structs which are packed in the same way so that they appear exactly the same in memory, what I don't know is what C++/CLI type I can use as parameters for functions that take pointers to C# structs, and can be passed to the C++ code.

Thanks.

Comment: If you show some code, you can get a real answer other than links to some MSDN pages like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173184.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any special “C++/CLI type”, you need just the C++ type. If it is a simple C-like `struct` (no virtual method tables or anything like that), then you could try using [`Marshal::StructureToPtr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx). If it's not that simple, you probably need to copy it from the C# object field by field.

Comment: In order to use `StructureToPtr` you will need to declare a `StructLayoutAttribute`, usually `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]`.

Comment: @J.N., he did say that the C# structures are already laid out in the memory in the same way as the C++ structures, so I was assuming he already uses `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` or `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` with the correct `[FieldOffset]`s.